# NaN the second time i press the ''Button''

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
let  input = document.getElementById('input');
let button = document.getElementById('btn');
let output = document.getElementById('totalTip');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input = input.value;
   output.innerHTML = (input * 5) + ' $';
   
});
```

I created a little function to calculate `input * 5`, but everytime I try to enter another number, I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'value' of undefined at HTMLButtonElement.button.addEventListene.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    input = input.value;
   output.innerHTML = input * 5 + ' $';
   
});
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: try `(e) => {` and `input = e.target.value`

Comment: How are you assigning input?

Comment: We'll need all of your code to fix this - you haven't pasted any HTML code, nor your full JavaScript.

Comment: there isn't enough code here to figure out what's wrong. You're problem is in the sentence you stated, `input` is undefined

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I think when they hit the button, they want to read an input field, which means that wouldn't work.

Comment: `Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`: your `input` variable is not defined. in this method's scope.

Answer (score 0):

The 1st time round `input` is an `Element` and in your event callback you redefine `input` as a `Number` or a `String` with `input = input.value;`.

This means the 2nd time round you're trying to get `.value` of something like `10` which doesn't exist so `undefined * 5` `===` `NaN`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be the type of thing you are going for:

html:

```
<button>Click for 5x</button>
<input type="text">
<div class="output"</div>
```

js: Here's is your problem, the input value is a `String`, you need to cast to `Number` with `parseInt` before multiplying by 5

```
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const output = document.querySelector('.output');

button.addEventLister('click', () => {
  const number = parseInt(input.value)
  output.innerHTML = number * 5 + ' $';
})
```

Also as a note, you shouldn't reassign input in this click event. So instead use a different variable name to assign the temporary input value.

Comment: i think that probably has to do with the fact that you are reassigning what input is in the click event, read the last sentence in my answer